# Convert date string to unix timestamp with no offset

Tags: php

I have a date string of `2014-06-23T090728Z` and want to convert it to a unix timestamp. I can do this fine but when the conversion takes place, my localtime is thrown into the mix and I wind up with a timestamp, that wnen converted, is different than what the initial string was.

How do I convert `2014-06-21 06:03:00` to unix time, that when converted back, will be exactly what I started out with?

Comment: make sure you set the right timezone, then. since your string ends with `Z`, it's probably UTC timestamp, so set your PHP to be in UTC as well.

Comment: The problem is, the dates are from all over the US, and have different timezones. I only care about the time that the string shows, irrelevant to my localtime.

Comment: unless you know what timezones those strings came from, then you're stuck.

Comment: OK, Marc, thanks. This saves me some hair pulling time. Maybe to avoid this issue, I'll save the strings as strings instead of timestamps.

Comment: storing as timestamps is better, but you'd need to store the TZ information as well. e.g. store everything as UTC, then use the stored TZ info to convert back to the user's local time.

Comment: Right... Because a UNIX timestamp is an epoch and needs to have the offset. OK.. I think I know what I need to do now, thanks. If you want to do a copy/paste of your comment below, I'll credit you for the answer.

Comment: naw. a timestamp is just number of seconds since midnight Jan 1/1970. There's nothing about the timestamps that requires that midnight to have been UTC or Tokyo and Adis-Abbaba time. It's just a number of seconds. timezones are metadata.

Comment: Exactly, but a date string when converted to a unix timestamp needs to have a local timezone to calculate from.. a starting point, no?

Comment: Which is where `date_set_default_timezone()` comes in.

Comment: Right. which is set to `UTC` on my local dev machine. On my server, it's `America/Los_Angeles`. So, I get two different time conversions depending on the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

php function strtotime(), will help you - http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using `strtotime` and date. The issue is the offset and I don't see an option for `date` to handle this